# How can I include a 3rd party package when I build in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program that relies on the user having third party packages already installed.  Is there any way to include those packages in my installer, or will they have to install them separately?  I'm using distutils in 2.7 if it matters.

Comment: Any options to use setuptools instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the complexity of the 3rd party package. If it is pure python, you may simply bundle it with the rest of your code. If it needs a more complicated install process, you will probably need users to install it themselves.

Comment: It is pure python.  How would I go about bundling it with my code?

Comment: Just treat it as if it were your own code and install it the normal way with distutils [like this](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) if it's a package.